# Can't increase Scala Eclipse heap size

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

I read the [docs](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/Setup) and append the given snipped in my eclipse.ini. I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse), and concluded that since I'm on Linux, I have to substitute -XX:MaxPermSize, but that changed nothing either.

I get this error when trying to launch eclipse:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/java/default/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=64m
-Xss1M
-server
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-jar /home/pc/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/pc/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/pc/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345/eclipse_1310.so
-startup /home/pc/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-exitdata 1ab0003
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/java/default/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=64m
-Xss1M
-server
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-jar /home/pc/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
```

I have the latest 2.9 scala plugin with Helios Eclipse.(Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911)

Comment: There's another thing that you must realize -- *everything* after the `-vmwargs` line is passed as args to the Java VM. The lines before are passed to the Eclipse application. So file like yours where there are *two* `-vmargs` lines look highly suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
```

and only use

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

The relevant parts of my eclipse.ini look like this:

```
-vmargs
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
-Xss2m
-server
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, can you post a complete sample on how your Eclipse.ini looks like? Mine looks like this unmodified: https://gist.github.com/955935 . I took your advice as to remove the last line and add the stuff from the docs instead.

Comment: you did not actually increase the heap size. That is done with e.g. -Xmx1024m.

Comment: I did that now, but it shows only 483mb max inside Eclipse. If I remove --launcher.XXMaxPermSize and add the other one, it crashes.

Comment: The [eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) seems to indicate you should have only one argument/option per line. Have you tried splitting out the size arguments onto their own lines?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, I think Eclipse just shows less max heap until it actually needs more than 400. It went to 500 for a short time, so I think the issue is fixed now.